# Nil is incompatible with return type 'MKClusterAnnotation'

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, ios11

With iOS 11 the default behavior is for annotations in a map view to cluster together as you zoom out. I don't want that to happen for my use case so I am trying to disable this default behavior. I have attempted to disable it by returning `Nil` from the optional **MKMapViewDelegate** method like so:

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, clusterAnnotationForMemberAnnotations memberAnnotations: [MKAnnotation]) -> MKClusterAnnotation {
    return nil // error on this line
}
```

But see the error: `Nil is incompatible with return type 'MKClusterAnnotation'`

I have tried the following as well to no avail:

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, clusterAnnotationForMemberAnnotations memberAnnotations: [MKAnnotation]) -> MKClusterAnnotation {
    return MKClusterAnnotation.init(memberAnnotations: [])
}
```

**Edit:**

As per [Marcel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/527691/marcel)'s suggestion I implemented the following, but I still see the same behavior:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didAdd views: [MKAnnotationView]) {
    for view in views {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            view.displayPriority = .required
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function is optional in `MKMapViewDelegate`, so you don't have to implement it. When you do implement it, it's return value is non-optional. So you have to return a `MKClusterAnnotation`, that's why you are getting a compile error.

Try setting the `displayPriority` of all your `MKAnnotationView`s to `MKFeatureDisplayPriority.required`.

See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkfeaturedisplaypriority/2867301-required

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I attempted your suggestion, but didn't see any difference. Consult my question for updated details.